# Is there a PMO certification for PMO Directors?

Tags: certification, pmo

I have my PMP and currently a PMO Director. However, does anyone know of a certification for PMOs?

Comment: Certification for PMO's or for PMO directors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UK Cabinet Office has a set of standards integrated with PRINCE2. These include a [Portfolio, Programme and Project Offices (P3O) guidance](http://www.p3o-officialsite.com/). According to their intro, P3O is intended to "provide universally applicable guidance that will enable individuals and organisations to successfully establish, develop and maintain appropriate business support structures that will allow:

- Informed senior management decision making on strategic alignment, prioritisation, risk management, optimisation of resource etc to successfully deliver their business objectives (portfolio management)
- Identification and realisation of business outcomes and benefits via programmes
- Successful delivery of project outputs that enable benefits within time, cost and quality restraints."

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, There is no specific certification for PMO Directors. Most prominent ones are PMP and Prince2.

You may check the available [PMI Certifications](http://www.pmi.org/Certification/What-are-PMI-Certifications.aspx). The site also allows you to [choose the right certification for you](http://www.pmi.org/Certification/Which-PMI-Certification-is-Right-for-You.aspx).

Comment: I checked the PMI site they have a Program and Portfolio level certification but not one specifically for PMO leaders/directors. There are a bunch of websites offering certifications but wondering if the market is recognizing them.

Comment: PMI have started with PgMP for Program Managers. I think that may be relevant to your requirement. In most cases PMP is sufficient. From this month they have upgraded PMP to v5 which covers some other aspects like stakeholders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pmocertified.com/members/pmoc/ecommerce/00000001/Project-Management-Office-PMO-Certification-PMOC.html+PracticalSolutions

I had found the above. Please see if this helps.

Comment: Please try to summarize the relevant content of the link; this guards against link-rot and helps people to decide whether they want to follow the link or not. It also slightly diminishes the chance of being rick-rolled.